# Subset number of rows per group based on a value in another dataframe

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, group-by, subset

I have read through similar questions, but mine is slightly different. I have a dataframe (df1) with more than 3 million rows, 1874 species (scientific_name) and total value.

[image]

I also have another dataframe (df2) which provides the number of rows I want to keep per species (in total around 2 million rows).

[image]

What I would like to do is subset/filter df1 as per the number of rows specified in df2, keeping only those rows with the highest total value. E.g. let imagine that Cypraeidae in df2 n.at.70 = 1104 (rather than 1), so I would like the resulting df to retain 1104 rows starting with the highest total value to the 1104th highest total value for that species (scientific_name).

I have been unable to achieve this for one species, let alone come up with an effective 'apply' or 'for' loop, so any help would be greatly appreciated, I am relatively new to R.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with, including a workable sample of data, not pictures of it. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, mostly because the 2 pictures of data you included don't seem to recreate the issue

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are manipulating large data sets - a `data.table` solution might be faster and preferable.

One approach is to merge in the `n.at.70` value to `df1`, put in descending order of `total`, and then show the top `n.at.70` results using `head`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

setkey(df1, scientific_name)
setkey(df2, scientific_name)

df2[df1, on = "scientific_name"][
  order(-total), head(.SD, n.at.70[1]), by = scientific_name]
```

A `tidyverse` equivalent might be the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%
  group_by(scientific_name) %>%
  arrange(scientific_name, desc(total)) %>%
  slice(1:n.at.70[1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the tidyverse equivalent is excellent. I am just reading about slice, very handy!

Comment: You can also check out `top_n` as well.